Cookies not working in Safari iOS, but works in Android and Desktop
I have an AppScript web app that uses cookies to store if a user is "Registered". If that's the case it lets the user use a Cupon. The app works fine when used in Android and desktop browsers. But when using it with an iPhone (mobile Safari) it stops working correctly.
Here's how the cookie setting and reading works:
function getCookie(cname) {
            let name = cname + "=";
            let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
            let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                let c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1);
                }
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }

        function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
            const d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            let expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
        }

And here's how the cookies are used:
switch (action) {
                case "register":
                    if (userid) {
                        setCookie(STORAGE_KEY, userid, 1)
                        $('#success').html(`<i class="bi bi-person-check-fill"></i> Te has registrado con el usuario: <b>${userid}</b>`);
                        $('#success').show();
                    } else {
                        setCookie(STORAGE_KEY, "", 1)
                        $('#error').html(`<i class="bi bi-exclamation-circle-fill"></i> No se pudo registrar el usuario.`);
                        $('#error').show();
                    }
                    break;

                case "checkin":
                    var regUserid = getCookie(STORAGE_KEY);
                    if (!regUserid) {
                        $('#error').html(`<i class="bi bi-exclamation-circle-fill"></i> Debes registrarte para fichar.`);
                        $('#error').show();
                    } else {
                        $('#loader').show();
                        google.script.run
                            .withSuccessHandler(function (ret) {
                                $('#loader').hide();
                                if (ret === false) {
                                    $('#error').html(`<i class="bi bi-exclamation-circle-fill"></i> El cupón ya existe. No puedes fichar de nuevo con el mismo cupón.`);
                                    $('#error').show();
                                } else {
                                    $('#success').html(`<i class="bi bi-alarm"></i> ${ret}<br/><b>${control}</b>: ${regUserid}`);
                                    $('#success').show();
                                }
                            })
                            .withFailureHandler(function (err) {
                                $('#error').html(`<i class="bi bi-exclamation-circle-fill"></i> Se ha producido un error: ${err}`);
                                $('#loader').hide();
                                $('#error').show();
                            })
                            .checkin(regUserid, control);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    var regUserid = getCookie(STORAGE_KEY);
                    if (!regUserid) {
                        $('#error').html(`<i class="bi bi-exclamation-circle-fill"></i> Debes registrarte para fichar.`);
                        $('#error').show();
                    } else {
                        $('#success').html(`<i class="bi bi-person-badge"></i> Estás registrad@ como <b>${regUserid}</b>`);
                        $('#success').show();
                    }
                    break;
            }

